# How to cleanly handle errors with struct state?

Tags: go

So I'm just getting my feet wet with Go, and I'm trying to cleanly handle errors in the Go-way. One result is that having a `type Movie struct` with methods to update the record, and sync to a data store. So an example method:

```
func (movie Movie) SetTitle(title string) : error {
    prevTitle := movie.Title
    movie.Title = title
    json, err := json.Marshal(movie)
    if (err != nil) {
        movie.Title = prevTitle
        return err
    }

    err = db.SetValue(movie.id, json)
    if (err != nil) {
        movie.Title = prevTitle
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The issue above is the 'cleanup' for a failed operation is to save the previous state, and restore as appropriate. But this feels very unmaintainable - it's so easy for a new error check to be made in the future, only to return without the proper cleanup. This would get even worse with multiple such 'cleanups'.

So to contrast, in other languages, I would wrap the whole bit in a try/catch, and handle cleanup just inside a single catch block. Here, I can:

1. Create a copy of `movie`, do all the stuff on the copy, and then only copy back to the original object once everything is successful
2. Change the logic to:

```
if json, err := json.Marshal(movie); err == nil {
  if err = db.SetValue(...); err == nil {
    return nil
  }
}

movie.Title = prevTitle;
return err
```

Which works, but I don't love having a level of nesting per check.

3. Change the error return to indicate it was updated locally, but not saved
4. Do it as described above
5. Break out the save logic into an `func Update() : err` function to minimize the number of checks needed (just thought of  this - think I like this one)

I feel like none of these are perfect; am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Two approaches that come to mind: 1. use `defer` for cleanup, 2. delegate to an unexported method, do cleanup in the exported one, do all the logic in the unexported one. [example](https://play.golang.com/p/OkyzHis2SDk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

The way you are persisting can cause numerous problems:

- you could incandescently mutate original object
- you mix different layers in one method, it makes code very fragile
- method, does too much

I suggest, separate update and persistence.
[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g-01tAWzvVa)

```
type Movie struct {
    id    int
    Title string
}

func (m *Movie) Persist() error {
    json, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Storing in db: %s", json)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    m := &Movie{1, "Matrix"}
    m.Title = "Iron Man"

    if err := m.Persist(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

}
```

---

### Old answer

In your example you use by-value receiver. In this case, you get a copy of the struct in the method, you free to modify that copy, but all changes will not be visible outside.

```
func (movie Movie) SetTitleValueSemantic(title string) error {
    movie.Title = title
    json, err := json.Marshal(movie)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Serialized: %s", json)

    return nil
}
```

playgorund: https://play.golang.org/p/mVnQ66TCaG9

---

I would strongly recommend avoiding such a coding style.
In case you REALLY need some of this kind, here is an example for inspiration:

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rHacnsRLkEE

```
func (movie *Movie) SetTitle(title string) (result *Movie, e error) {
    movieCopy := new(Movie)
    *movieCopy = *movie
    result = movie

    defer func() {
        if e != nil {
            result = movieCopy
        }
    }()

    movie.Title = title
    serialized, e := json.Marshal(movie)
    if e != nil {
        return
    }

    log.Printf("Serialized: %s", serialized)

    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you elaborate on what style is more idiomatic, if not this?

Comment: I would split data and persistence logic, for example: https://play.golang.org/p/QNzGxwrOtUv

if it helped, pls accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alexey is correct, but if the `Movie` struct has pointer or slice fields, they wouldn't be copied.

Here's an example that manually copies the slice field (`Tags`) before every update, and also features a nice transaction method (`update`) I think you could use:

```golang
type Movie struct {
    id int
    Title string
    Year int
    Tags []string
}

func (m *Movie) update(fn func(m *Movie) error) error {
    // Make a copy of Movie.
    movieCopy := *m

    // Manually copy slice and pointer fields.
    movieCopy.Tags = make([]string, 0, len(m.Tags))
    copy(movieCopy.Tags, m.Tags)

    // Run the update transaction on the copy.
    if err := fn(&movieCopy); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Save to db.
    data, err := json.Marshal(movieCopy)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return db.SetValue(m.id, data)
}

func (m *Movie) SetTitle(title string) error {
    m.update(func(mm *Movie) error {
        mm.Title = title
        return nil
    })
}

func (m *Movie) SetYear(year int) error {
    m.update(func(mm *Movie) error {
        mm.Year = year
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: You are correct, it create shallow copy. I will clarify this point in my answer.